# Custom area wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have been trying to find contents about Wordpress. I would like to learn how to create custom fields in my wordpress theme, just like this one, on the screenshot below. Unfortunatelly, I ccouldn't find anything about it. So If someone can help me I thank you.

[image: Custom fields]

Comment: I think its easy use html in page ...[check this link](https://shibulijack.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/create-custom-forms-in-wordpress/)

Comment: @narasimharaosp - You misunderstand the question.  He wants to create custom "theme" settings.

Comment: This is the documentation you are looking for.  Read it, and then Google for any questions / issues you have: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

Comment: Thanks, I will study this documentation.